# How to format txt file and import into jquery to use inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have an external txt file with a list of words. I need to format this txt file so that jQuery see's each word individually separated by a comma.

I then need to import the txt file into my js file and input the words inside the txt file inside a variable.

Can someone help me achieve this? Or maybe an alternative method to achieve this same function? This is quite confusing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

so instead of writing in my jquery file like:

```
var pbfFilterWords = ['baby bullet', 'back2life', 'black & decker'];
```

it would be like this:

```
var pbfFilterWords = [word-list.txt] // not sure what goes in the brackets here
```

word-list.txt

```
baby bullet, back2life, black & decker
```

pbf.js

```
jQuery.get('word-list.txt', function(data) {
    alert(data);
 });

 // Function for filter button
 $('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html;
 $('#pbf-filter').click(function(){
     var $pbfOutput = $('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html();
     // Array of words for filter

     **var pbfFilterWords = [data]; // THIS IS WHERE THE TXT FILE NEEDS TO GO**


         // Output to new DIV and remove specified keywords from pbfFilterWords
         $('.pbf-link-output').html($pbfOutput);
         // To make pbfFilterWords not case sensitive
         $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
             return function( elem ) {
             return $(elem).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
                 };
         });
         // Function to output the filtered words
         $.each(pbfFilterWords , function(i , val){
         $('.pbf-link-output > div:contains("'+val+'")').remove();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to split the string into an array.

```
$.get('word-list.txt', function(data) {
  var pbfFilterWords = data.split(', ');
  pbfFilterWords.forEach(function(word) {
    console.log(word);
  });
});
```

I added a for-each loop as an example of looping over each word in the text file.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to split the data by words with this function. However would you now how I can import that txt file inside a variable in my js file?

Comment: In my example above, the variable `data` contains the raw txt contents and the variable `pbfFilterWords` contains the array of words. Any additional code can be added after `pbfFilterWords` which I demonstrated with a for-each loop (something you would typically do with an array is to iterate over each item in the array).